# AngularJs select add option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I work with angularjs and select options collection. If I added in html option tags all works good. But if i try added item from angular it is not working.

My code:

```
<div ng-controller="statisticsTableController">
  <select ng-model="publishersdata" 
          ng-options="s for s in publishersdata"
          chosen option="publishersdata">
  </select>
</div>
```

and AngularJs code:

```
function statisticsTableController($scope, $http) {
  var publishersArray = [];

  $http.get('/api/getAllItems').success(function(data) {  
    angular.forEach(data, function(data) {
      publishersArray.push(data.Name);
    });
  });

  this.publishersdata = publishersArray;
  //...
}
```

Why it is not working? And how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

After changes:

```
function statisticsTableController($scope, $http) {
    var publishersArray = [];

    $http.get('/api/getAllItems')
        .success(function (data) {
            angular.forEach(data, function (data) {
                publishersArray.push(data.Name);
            });
        });

    $scope.publishersdata = publishersArray;
    //...
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="statisticsTableController">
  <select multiple 
          ng-model="publishersdata" 
          ng-options="s for s in publishersdata"
          chosen option="publishersdata">
  </select>
</div>
```

It is not working properly

Comment: push your data in $scope.publishersdata in your controller

Comment: One thing you shud be doing is change your `ng-model` name.

Comment: Sorry I don't  understand. Can you explain me.

Comment: @TarasKovalenko your `ng-model` and `ng-options` array name are same, change one of them. this may cause problems.

Comment: Not working if I edit  ng-model="publishersdata" to  ng-model="publishers" . Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the code instead of data use value in argument of foreach

```
angular.forEach(data, function (value) {
           publishersArray.push(value.Name);
 });
```

Comment: what issue you have faced

Comment: what data you get from console i want it

Comment: I not get exception in browser console

Comment: I want your scuccess response output console.log(data)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77870/discussion-between-taras-kovalenko-and-jqueryking).

Comment: But if i remove one item from page i cant select them again

Comment: Sorry if remove means you will araise another question i answered for your current question add. Thanks

Comment: Raise your question with remove code in your controller

Comment: New question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254475/angularjs-select-and-unselect-oprion

Answer (score 1):

One problem that i see is that both your `ng-model` and your `ng-options` point to the same `publishersdata` object which might be one of the causes this brakes. Your `ng-model` should be an object which contains what is selected in the dropdown.

Also as posted above, you should attach `publishersdata` to `$scope`, otherwise it will not be accessible in the HTML

Other than that this looks fine to me.